# IBM Process Designer - find all Java class references

Tags: java, ibm-bpm

My team inherited a system to support and develop and it's mostly created in IBM Process Designer with some functionality coming from external Java classes.

Documentation is missing or incomplete (what a surprise!) so I need to make some kind of "architecture map" for further refactoring based on the existing implementation.
So the question is: what's the best way to find and list all calls to Java integration components (ideally, to all Java methods) in IBM PD? Going process by process manually is a big troublesome because solution is rather complex.

Comment: I guess chances are really small that you get any reasonable answer here. Try if you can get your hands on an IBM ID and post on some forums around http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ ... you see, in the end you are asking for support for some 3rd party tool. One that IBM makes money with. Guess there aren't too many people around who would help on that ... for well, free.

Comment: Thanks! Probably that's what I'll have to do. This is something new to us and knowledge is minimal. Even googling for keywords does not give straight answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

If you go to Snapshots in Process Center you can export Installation Package to local machine. Unzip it, then unzip export.twx and in Objectss folder you'll find XML representation of all objects.
Search for 'javaClassName' string and you'll get the list.

Unfortunately I had to use this workaround because default tab "Where is used" in PD did not provide any information.